# How to call luasql script from .NET

Tags: c#, lua, zerobrane, luasql

I am using ZeroBrane IDE for lua script and Visual Studio 2015 for C#
I can call lua script from C# with normal variable, but I can't run the script with sql-odbc, it's working in zeroBrane only but from c# I can't.

**here is c# code**

```
try
{
   Lua lua = new Lua();
   lua.DoFile("DGT_MSID.lua");

   var x = lua.DoString("return GetData()");
   Console.WriteLine(x.First().ToString());
} catch(NLua.Exceptions.LuaScriptException ex)
{
   Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

**DGT_MSID.lua script**

```
function GetData()
  require "luasql.odbc"
  env = assert(luasql.odbc())
  print(env)
  con = assert(env:connect("conan", "sa", "p@ssw0rd"))
  print(con)
  cur = assert (con:execute"use testdb")
  cur = assert (con:execute"SELECT MSISD FROM MSID")
  row = cur:fetch({}, "a")

  while row do
    print(string.format("%s",row.MSISD))
    row = cur:fetch (row, "a")
  end

  cur:close()
  con:close()
  env:close()

  return row.MSISD
end
```

Here is this error:

> error loading module 'luasql.odbc' from file
>   '...\Debug\luasql\odbc.dll':The specified module could not be found

Comment: Have you copied the dll into the desired location?

Comment: all .dll files its already in luasql folder in debug directory.

Comment: An issue i had with using `nlua` was that the `require("luasql.odbc")` would only look outside of my `lua` folder so if i had `..\lua\lua_odbc.lua` and `..\lua\luasql\odbc.dll` it would only look for `..\luasql\odbc.dll` and fail to find it

Comment: its working only with lua51, and NLua using lua52, how to solve this issue ??

Answer (score 0):

I suspect one of the dependencies of odbc.dll is missing or not being loaded (which may be the Lua DLL or some other library it's linked against). You can use [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to get the list of dependencies and even run your application in "profile" mode, which will show all loaded DLLs as well as any failing loads and their related errors.

Comment: The odbc.dll working only with lua51.dll, it's not working with lua53 or lua52, and NLua using only lua52.dll !!!???

Comment: That's expected, as each dll is compiled only against specific Lua interpreter. You need to compile odbc.dll against lua52 to get it working with NLua. You may try [twoface](http://corsix.github.io/twoface/) to see if it works for your project ("twoface is a DLL which consumes the 5.2 ABI and presents a 5.1 style ABI, thereby allowing a 5.2 program to load most 5.1 C libraries without the need for any recompilation.")